# Encrypt large data using public key .ASC in php

Tags: php, public-key-encryption, pgp

I have a public key with extension .asc that I need to use to encrypt data and to send it in a plain text file. I am trying to accomplish this in a windows machine using php. Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: In PECL, there is a gnupg extension  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php

Comment: rocket-hazmat: I don't have any problem configuring it in linux. Windows is what being a pain... I was hoping to find the dll I can refer to within the INI file but I don't see any out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you [installed the gnupg extension for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gnupg.installation.php).

```
$gpg = new gnupg();
$publicData = file_get_contents('public.asc');
$publicKey = $gpg->import($publicData);
$gpg->addencryptkey($publicKey['fingerprint']);
echo $gpg->encrypt('Data to encrypt');
```

Instead of encrypting a constant, replace by the file contents, and store the encrypted message wherever you want.

Comment: gnupg extension isn't that straight forward in windows. I tried installing it using PECL but getting an error "ERROR: The DSP gnupg.dsp does not exist." I may have to compile it from the source ...

Comment: You might be happier just calling the binary. Make sure to put the public key into the web servers GnuPG directory, and just call `gpg.exe -r DEADBEEF -d file-to-encrypt >encrypted-file.asc`. You might have to use GnuPG's full path. Or simply use a Linux box as web server...

Comment: Not a bad idea. Thanks Jens Erat.

Answer (score 0):

first create new folder owner by www-data

```
mkdir /var/www/.gnupg
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /var/www/.gnupg
```

second try follow php code:

```
    putenv("GNUPGHOME=/var/www/.gnupg");
    $gpg = new gnupg();
    $publicData = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/web/resources/keys/public.asc');
    $privateData = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/web/resources/keys/SECRET.asc');
    $publicKey = $gpg->import($publicData);
    $gpg->addencryptkey($publicKey['fingerprint']);
    $encrypt = ($gpg->encrypt('Data to encrypt'));
    echo $encrypt;
```